# Calling a function from Android Library

Tags: android

I have created an **Android Project** and a **Library Project** and added the library to the main project by following the steps in [android developers website](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html). I also created a class (**SpecificOperations.java**) in the library project.

Now, I need to know how to import and call a function from **SpecificOperations.java**, in my main app. As an assumption: I want to call **takeTheCube(int i)** function from this class. Thanks for help!

#### **SOLVED!**

Thanks for replies, I solved the issue through [**this article**](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html).

Comment: Sounds like you're using a full-fledged IDE, such as Eclipse. Add that name to a google query, and you'll have this solved :)